# qsort doesnt change my array order

Tags: c, function, structure

i have an array of structures (Employee):

```
typedef struct Employee{
    char name[MAX_SIZE];
    int salary;
    int experience;
} employee_t;
```

i want to reorder my array by salary, i have created a comperator:

```
int compareEmployeesBySalary(const void* a, const void* b){
        employee_t* one = (employee_t*)a;
        employee_t* two = (employee_t*)b;

        if (one->salary == two->salary)
            return 0;
        else if (one->salary > two->salary)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }


void main()
{
    int i;

    employee_t** employeeArray = (employee_t**)malloc(sizeof(employee_t*)*5);

    for(i=0 ; i < 2 ; i++)
    {
        employeeArray[i] = (employee_t*)malloc(sizeof(employee_t));
        readEmployee( employeeArray[i] ); //input for 5 employee's
    }

    puts("");
    puts("beforesort\n");
    for(i=0; i <2 ; i++)
    {
        printEmployee(employeeArray[i]);
    }
    puts("--------------------------------------------------------");
    puts("after salary sort\n");

    qsort(&employeeArray, 2, sizeof(employee_t), compareEmployeesBySalary);
    for(i=0; i < 2 ; i++)
        printEmployee( employeeArray[i] );
}
```

when i run it normally it just prints the original array by the order i insert the employees, but when im debugging it prints by my compare function,
why is that?

thank you!!!

Comment: You might have be running the outdated release version binary, while the debug version is rebuilt every time.

Comment: `qsort(&employeeArray…` doesn't look right. shouldn't that be `qsort(employeeArray…`?

Comment: @Eugene Sh i do i solve this?

Comment: but when im debugging it prints by my compare function -- What do you mean? Is it like, Code works if you put breakpoint?

Comment: rebuild the release version as well?

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant i tried that to, same result

Comment: @Swanand yes, if i put breakpoits and go stepover all my program is works

Comment: Don't try to reason about code that invokes UB (working as expected is a valid form of UB, although in this case it is certainly odd). First fix the type mismatch problems (see my answer); if that still doesn't work (although I tested it here), then we can talk about debugging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
qsort(&employeeArray, 2, sizeof(employee_t), compareEmployeesBySalary);
```

To:

```
qsort(employeeArray, 2, sizeof(employee_t *), compareEmployeesBySalary);
```

The first argument must be `employeeArray` because the `qsort()` function receives a pointer to the start of the array, not a pointer to a pointer to the start of the array. Plus, you have an array of pointers, not an array of `employee_t`, so the 3rd argument must be `sizeof(employee_t *)`.

Finally, change your compare function to:

```
int compareEmployeesBySalary(const void* a, const void* b){
        employee_t* one = *(employee_t **)a;
        employee_t* two = *(employee_t **)b;

        if (one->salary == two->salary)
            return 0;
        else if (one->salary > two->salary)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
}
```

Because again, what you have is an array of pointers, so `a` and `b` will be of type `employee_t **`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's odd. The code as is invokes UB, so I'd blame it on that - although I find it hard to believe that it works in the debugger, but he might just be lucky. OTOH, when I tested with my modifications it worked like a charm.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds unlikely

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see is that you pass `sizeof(employee_t)` into the size parameter of qsort, whereas your array only stores pointers to `employee_t`. I suggest you try replacing `sizeof(employee_t)` in `qsort` with `sizeof(employee_t*)`.